# Python limit of the * operator and zip() function

Tags: python, memory, zip

I have a Python code similar to this one:

```
for lines in zip(*files):
   # do something
```

where `files` is a list of files, each `file` is a list of `lines` and each `line` is a list of `string`s. Therefore, the code above should first unpack the list `files` and then apply the function `zip()`, returning a tuple with the first line of each file. The problem is that this works just fine, **if** the length of the list of files is 30 (for example). However, if the lenght is bigger, for instance, 120, the code inside the loop doesn't get executed even once.

The conclusion is that either the `zip()` function is returning an empty list or the `*` operator is not doing its job. Either way, my question is if there is a limit in the arguments that `zip()` can handle (or `*` can unpack) or it is somehow limited by the amount of memory that my computer has, since I haven't been able to find anything in Python's documentation.

PS: I'm running Python 2.4

Comment: Are you sure that each of your files contains at least one line? If not, maybe use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: `izip_longest()` is not available on Python 2.4, but otherwise you have probably nailed it.  On Python 2.4, you can use the cryptic `map(None, *files)` instead of `izip_longest()`.

Comment: Please provide a **short** example of the `files` structure.  Please include the output of `zip(*the_short_example)`.  Your wordy description is not as helpful as an actual display  of the first few items in `files`.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Yes, that was the problem. There was one file in the second list that was empty, and `zip()` truncates the output to the length of the smallest list. Therefore, it was returning an empty list.

Comment: @S.Lott I thought the actual structure would be even more confusing, but I would provide a short example:

    `files = [[[elem11, elem12, elem13] [elem21 elem22 elem23]]]`

Comment: @skd: Your "conclusion is that either the zip() function is returning an empty list or the * operator is not doing its job" is false.  Therefore, the `files` structure is much more likely to be the problem.   If it's confusing, it's probably wrong.

Comment: @@skd: Please **update** the question with the example data and the example output from `zip(the_example_data)`.  Do not post code in a comment.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer, since it turned out to be on spot.

Comment: It's easy to convince yourself that `zip` and `*` do in fact work.  Here you go:  `print zip(*([range(2)] * 1000))`.

Comment: @skd: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it as correct using the tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If one of the files is empty, `zip` will return an empty list. As of Python 2.6 you can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to handle that. On older versions, you can use `map(None, *files)`, courtesy of @Sven Marnach.